# RegistrationExistsAsync returns current status of registartion or not ? when user uninstalls the app also

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, push-notification

Does the method RegistrationExistsAsync in azure notification hub always return the current status of the registration . i.e . when user uninstalls the app whether it will be updated  on calling this method "RegistrationExistsAsync" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe `RegistrationExistsAsync(string registrationId)` will work for your particular scenario. Azure Notification Hub will unregister devices in the following manor:

1. Custom code utilizing the SDK to de-register the device from the service
2. An "INVALID" response status code from PNS when a push notification is sent to the target device.
3. The device registration TTL is exceeded

For determining whether or not a device is no longer registered, it's recommended to inspect the PNS response code following sending a push notification to the target device.